# Query Doesn't Re-run after navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-navigation

I have a screen where I am using a query like this:

```
export const AllFriends: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const { data, error } = useGetMyProfileQuery({
    onCompleted: () => {
      console.log('hellooo')
    },
  });
```

Every time I visit this page from the home-page, I think the query re-runs as I always see the `hello`log. Similarly, from this page, I visit another screen like this:

```
          <Text
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('PendingRequests')}>
            Pending Requests (
            {data
              ? data.me.pendingUserRelationsRequestsReceived.totalCount
              : ''}
            )
          </Text>
```

Every time I visit this screen, I see the **hellooo from pending again**. This screen looks like this:

```
export const ReceivedPendingRequests: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const { data, error } = useGetMyProfileQuery({
    onCompleted: () => {
      console.log('hellooo from pending')
    },
  });

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.safeView}>
      <Container style={styles.container}>
        <Text
          style={styles.backText}
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('AllFriends')}>
          Zurück
        </Text>
      </Container>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

Now the problem is that when I navigate back to **AllFriends**, the query should re-run and I should see the `hello` log again just like I see when I come from the **Homepage** to **AllFriends**. But I don't.

However, if I come back from AllFriends to PendingRequests, I see the log **hellooo from pending** again.

Edit:

```
  useFocusEffect(()=>{
    getMyProfile()
  },[]);
  
  const getMyProfile = () => {
    const { data, error } = useGetMyProfileQuery({
      onCompleted: () => {
        console.log('hellooo')
      },
      //fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
    });
  }
```

Comment: is this navigation V5 ?

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan
```{ useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native": "^5.5.1",```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call **refetch** it will re-run the query for you. You can pass it to other screens aswell.

You can get it like this:

```
const {loading, data, refetch} = useQuery(Query, {})
```

Now in you useFocuseEffect just call this:

```
 useFocusEffect(()=>{
   React.useCallback(() => {
    refetch();
    }, [])
 },[]);
```

Comment: I have tried this in the past but the app kept randomly crashing and gave me ```typeError: (evaluating _this.currentObservable.query.refetch)```

Comment: What's your apollo-client version. It works fine for me in   "apollo-client": "^2.6.4",

Comment: react-hooks: "@apollo/react-hooks": "^3.1.3",

Comment: "@apollo/react-hooks": "^3.1.5",

Comment: Also your currect suggested solution gives me ```Expected 1 arguments, but got 2.```on the last dependency array

Comment: Maybe it's a bug in 3.1.5 try npm install @apollo/react-hooks@3.1.3

Comment: I will complete my query for you :) 

const {loading, data, refetch} = useQuery(Query, {
    fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
onCompleted: () => {
      console.log('hellooo')
    },
 

})

Comment: try adding fetch policy too

Comment: No, I mean in the useFocusEffect. For the first part, I am using a custom graphql hook with the necessary conditions

Answer (score -1):

when using `navigation.navigate` the screen doesn't "unmount", so it will not be reinitialized as fresh from the start as the screen does when you're using `navigation.replace`

Try using `navigation.replace` instead of `navigation.navigate`. I hope it helps, if not, let me know.

Comment: So I should use .replace instead?

Comment: yes, try it on this specific case. i updated the answer to add this haha

Comment: If I try using ```navigation.replace('AllFriends')```, I get an error that ```Property 'replace' does not exist on type 'NavigationProp<Record<string, object | undefined>, string, NavigationState, {}, {}>'.ts(2339)```

Comment: on my code i usually use `this.props.navigation.replace('screen')`. I'm searching something for you. But i'm pretty sure using `replace` is the way

Comment: as said here: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/8256

you can use `const navigation =  useNavigation<StackNavigationProp<{route: {} }>>()`
`navigation.replace('route');`

Can you try it?

Comment: Nope, it gives me an error that: Expected 2 arguments, but got 1. on replace